# How can I draw a rectangle with only one rounded corner using Canvas in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using Jetpack Compose to draw some custom shapes with Canvas. Specifically, I need to draw rectangles with only one rounded corner. I know that I can use `drawRoundRect` to draw rectangles with rounded corners, but it seems like it only allows me to set the radius for multiple corners at once.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [**`RoundRect`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/geometry/RoundRect) function where you can specify the corner radius for each corner.

Something like:

```
    Canvas(modifier= Modifier.fillMaxSize()){

        val cornerRadius = CornerRadius(25f, 25f)
        val path = Path().apply {
            addRoundRect(
                RoundRect(
                    rect = Rect(
                        offset = Offset(0f, 0f),
                        size = Size(100f, 100f),
                    ),
                    topLeft = cornerRadius, //just an example
                )
            )
        }
        drawPath(path, color = Color.Red)

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

RoundedCornerShape function has overloads that accepts params for corners in dp, Float or percentage

```
fun RoundedCornerShape(
    topStart: Dp = 0.dp,
    topEnd: Dp = 0.dp,
    bottomEnd: Dp = 0.dp,
    bottomStart: Dp = 0.dp
) = RoundedCornerShape(
    topStart = CornerSize(topStart),
    topEnd = CornerSize(topEnd),
    bottomEnd = CornerSize(bottomEnd),
    bottomStart = CornerSize(bottomStart)
)

/**
 * Creates [RoundedCornerShape] with sizes defined in pixels.
 */
fun RoundedCornerShape(
    topStart: Float = 0.0f,
    topEnd: Float = 0.0f,
    bottomEnd: Float = 0.0f,
    bottomStart: Float = 0.0f
) = RoundedCornerShape(
    topStart = CornerSize(topStart),
    topEnd = CornerSize(topEnd),
    bottomEnd = CornerSize(bottomEnd),
    bottomStart = CornerSize(bottomStart)
)
```

And you can draw outline from shape with

```
val shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 20.dp)
val density = LocalDensity.current
val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
```

Inside Canvas

```
drawOutline(
    shape.createOutline(
        size = size,
        density = density,
        layoutDirection = layoutDirection
    ),
    color = Color.Red
)
```